# `fetch` request not showing desired result, `ajax` request does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, fetch

I have two requests, one with `ajax` and one with `fetch`, the successor.

If I post my data with `fetch`, to the exact same (blackbox) API as `ajax`, the results are different.

**Ajax**

```
$.post(this.config.baseUrl + this.config.loginUrl, {
  username:this.username,
  password:this.password
})
  .done(data => {debugger;});

// result: {"jwt":"eyJ0eX..."}
```

**Fetch**

```
this.http.fetch(this.config.baseUrl + this.config.loginUrl, {
  method: 'post',
  body: json({
      username:this.username, 
      password: this.password
  })
})
  .then(response => {
    // let x = response.json();
    // If I uncomment the above, I get an error:
    // undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    debugger;
  });
```

result:

[image]

My main problem is that I need the `jwt` variable that `Ajax` returns, but in the `Fetch` implementation I don't get that variable in the response.

I hope one of you can explain to me eighter what I can do to alter the `Fetch` implementation, or to read the variable wich I guess would probably be in the `ReadableByteStream`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does `response.text().then(t => console.log(t))` output?

Comment: Thank you @robertklep, HTML it is. It seems that `Ajax` just ignores the HTML, while `Fetch` did not tell me the content type. It's a server-side issue. I'm going to call that team together for a fix :)

Comment: Are you sure this simply isn't an authentication failure? The `$.post` call sends a body formatted like `username=hello&password=world`, while I assume the `body: json(...)` causes the `fetch` call to send a body formatted like `{ "username":"hello, "password":"world" }`. I would assume (unless you have very robust server-side code) that the server is set up to read only one of those formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch returns an response which has some attributes and `body` is the one that you need. The datatype of body on fetch is a `ReadableByteStream`

On your case the easiest thing to do is convert it to json and that is quite simple :

```
this.http.fetch(this.config.baseUrl + this.config.loginUrl, {
  method: 'post',
  body: json({
      username:this.username, 
      password: this.password
  })
})
  .then(response => {response.json().jwt});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm going to update the question. If I do that, this pops up: `undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the `Accept` and/or `Content-Type` headers as needed. `$.post` makes a best guess on these based on the data you give it. The fetch api leaves it to the user.